# How can I attach files without using a plugin?

Tags: custom-field, attachments, media

I want to add files from my site or from external links with files to any of my posts, and be able to add the size of the file and choose which ones it will do "File Force" and which not. I want to have too a counter that it will show how many clicks/downloads the file had. Any link that I add to a post internal or external, I want it to have automatically rel noindex, nofollow. Is this possible to do with custom fields???

I also tried by adding media>external media, I inserted it to the post but it doesn't show it in the post, have I done something wrong or I have to something more to find out?

Comment: **Do not delete and re-ask questions!** Particularly when someone has already offered an answer!

Comment: ok, but it was another question in this post and I re-edited but I thought that it was better to make a new question and that's why I deleted it.

Comment: Yes, you should ask separate questions. If you ask a question that's answered, though, don't edit that question out. It makes the site hard to navigate, clutters your profile with a lot of duplicate posts, and leads to people flagging things for moderator attention.

Comment: -1 for _without using a plugin_ – this is pure plugin territory and should not be bundled to a theme. I strongly recommend to all readers not to follow this approach.

Comment: @toscho, Not really.  I have LOTS of functionality built into my themes that I don't see the point of putting into a plugin.  This is because my themes are not released to the public, but contain proprietary functionality.  The principals might be the same, whether you put it into a plugin or a themes functions.php file.  He might have a specific business case that makes a plugin something that he doesn't need/want.

Comment: @AaronWagner We don't care about very specialized edge cases, these are _too localized_. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used custom fields in the past to do something kinda like this.  You name each custom field the same, and then in the value, give it some separation character. I used ||.

Then you can do something like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach($custom as $c)
  $output[] = explode('||',$c);
```

Then you'll have an array of arrays with your information.  From there you should be able to do with it what you want.

I also wrote a shortcode to go along with this, that allowed me to display it anywhere in the page.  That allows you to have more flexibility, and you don't have to mess with a custom template.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your immediate response but I can't understand how I can use your answer to my question.

Comment: In the context of the original question, this made sense.  The original question was along the lines of "How to make a list of files for download"